# writing a code for a basic form in react with a submit button in react

Tags: reactjs

When I hit submit for the form, alert popup should be displayed, the submit button should be disabled till we close the the popup and then it should be enabled again .

Tried setting the initial state to false and then setting the state in submit function to true , but it is not working as the button gets disabled permanently unless I reload the page.

Not much is written as I don't know how to solve this issue.

I expect the submit button to be disabled till we close the alert popup and then get enabled but the submit button gets disabled permanently.

Comment: please, can you show your code?

Comment: Sorry code cannot be shared as nothing has been written , i have a brief idea where i set the validatedButton to false in the state and then in the submit function inside the axios call i  update the state to true , my button code - <button onClick={submitfunction} disabled={this.state.validateButton} >

Comment: It'll be more helpful if you provide the code. Thanks

Comment: whats the point, when you get an alert, the form is disabled until you click Ok on alert box..

Comment: @ZainUlAbideen  - have intitialized validatedButton to false in the initial state                         
add(e){
axios.post('http://localhost:8080/data',entries,config)
      .then( response => {
        console.log(response);
        if(response.status === 201){
            alert('Succesfull Entry')
            this.setState({
              validatedButton:true});
 }
     }
   }
<button className="btn btn-success mt-2 ml-2" onClick={(e)=>this.add(e)} disabled={this.state.validatedButton}>Add Schema</button>

Comment: @gopigorantala -  to prevent multiple submit during the submit , else before the data goes to the sever multiple times same data might be sent .

Comment: @nishant, so you want someone to click submit button once and then disable it until it finishes processing some data..   is this what you want ?

Comment: @gopigorantala - yes exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this**

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.click = this.click.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            buttonState: false
        }
    }

    click(event) {
        this.setState({
            buttonState: true
        });
        setTimeout(() => this.setState(
            {buttonState: false}),
            1000
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="button-state">
                <button disabled={this.state.buttonState} onClick={this.click}>Click Me</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: yes it is happening , but its getting disabled after i close the popup and gets enabled , but actually should happen during the popup is displayed , will figure that out  and let you know about the result

Comment: this has nothing to do with the pop-up, a timeout is set to wait for 1sec.. refactor your code accordingly to disable your button until the operation finishes..

Comment: if you are using promises, then its easy to achieve, lets say I use axios(an npm package) to get data asynchronously.. `axios.post('url').then(//enable button here)` When the button is clicked call a promise and then resolve it in the `then()`

Answer (score 0):

Use Window `confirm()` Method and setstate on its response. for more detail click [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp)

Comment: was suggested this method but did not work , the button was disabled even after closing the pop up

Comment: its working fine on my side

`this.setState({disabledBtn: true});`  


`confirm('are you sure');`  


`this.setState(() => ({disabledBtn: false}));`

can you please share your code

Comment: have intitialized validatedButton to false in the initial state                         
add(e){
axios.post('http://localhost:8080/data',entries,config)
      .then( response => {
        console.log(response);
        if(response.status === 201){
            alert('Succesfull Entry')
            this.setState({
              validatedButton:true});
 }
     }
   }
<button className="btn btn-success mt-2 ml-2" onClick={(e)=>this.add(e)} disabled={this.state.validatedButton}>Add Schema</button>

Comment: you can setstate to true for disabledBtn before sending a post request to the server and in .then of axios method, you can set that back to false, so that while the request is in progress user can't submit it again, and if the error cames you can print error using any toaster package like [react-toastify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-toastify/v/1.4.3)

Comment: Tayyab Razzaq - will try that out now